# how to sign in to google apps and my own site without provisioning api

Tags: api, provisioning, google-apps

Is there a way to make a one sign in site which will both sign to google apps and my site? I haven't got acces to provisioning api. The only idea how to do it that comes to my head is to somehow bypass it with curl. I'd love to know if there is any other solution, server side or client side. Please, help! I'm using django if that does change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a cookie for Google's site without being on Google's site. It is part of how Cookies work.

You can try and use Google's Single Sign-On function using the [documentation on this page](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html). You must be a paying apps account however, so this wouldn't work for you.

But even the single-sign on only provides a way to use a different authenticator for Google's services. You still have to go to Google's login page.

Comment: And given that Google is 'REALLY' worried about security, I doubt there is a loophole you can go through.